# Confusion with ordering of the color values in the bitmap buffer got from Bitmapfactory

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I decoded an image (JPEG) with Android `BitmapFactory` class and it decoded fine with color format `ARGB_8888`.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/camel.jpg",
            new BitmapFactory.Options());
    Log.d(TAG,"Color format of the bitmap : "+bitmap.getConfig());
```

I dumped the raw buffer from the `Bitmap` class

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

    Log.d(TAG,"Color format of the bitmap : "+bitmap.getConfig());

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/buffer.raw");
        outputStream.write(buffer.array());
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and examined the dump in a Hex editor , it looks like the ordering of the color components is not in the order A,R,G and B.

Instead it looks like ordering is R,G,B and A.

[image]

As seen above the alpha (FF) is in the end of the set of four bytes for a pixel.Also to corroborate this I opened the image in 7yuv and image is displayed properly with color format RGBA and little-endian encoding.

[image]

My confusion is why is Android reports the format of the Bitmap as `ARGB_8888` and actual byte ordering is R,G,B and A.

I was wondering this might be due to some endian mismatch , but in that case the whole ordering needs to be simply reversed (B,G,R and A).

Also I might be doing something wrong while dumping the bitmap to a raw buffer (and I am not very good at Java) , but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance!